# Unable to discover devices in smartThings

Tags: aws-lambda, iot, smartthings

I am developing an IOT device using smartThings.I am using aws lambda function for getting request and sending responses to the smartThings. I am getting request whenever smartThings app hitting lambda function and sending exact response to that request but still the discover devices are not showing in the smartThings app. Please help me

Refrence link:
https://smartthings.developer.samsung.com/docs/guides/smartthings-schema/smartthings-schema-reference.html#Interaction-types

the first image is the request that i am getting

[image]

2nd and 3rd images are the responses that i am getting according to the request

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't put your token public.

Comment: Are you using a SDK? If so, can you put the code ?

Comment: Download this zip file: https://www.filedropper.com/lambda

Comment: Thank you @Rubens_z, I solved my problem

Comment: if possible, post your solution as an answer.

Comment: nothing just keeping the default value of deviceHandleType in response i.e, "deviceHandlerType": "c2c-rgbw-color-bulb"

Answer (score 0):

By choosing the correct deviceHandlerType in response the devices started discovering. i.e.,  "deviceHandlerType": "c2c-rgbw-color-bulb" (reference link for implementing schema for smartThings https://smartthings.developer.samsung.com/develop/guides/smartthings-schema/implement-schema.html)

we can choose deviceHandlerType based on our requirement.